# For windows 10, is stopping a service different than shutting down a service?

Tags: windows-10, services

Basically the question is in the title. 
Now some background:

I have a service running. When I go to the services list I can see it "Running Automatic". With right-click I can "stop" it. Then I can see it "Stopped".

I also tried the command line. I typed

```
sc queryex [service-name]
```

then when I identified its PID I typed

```
taskkill /pid [PID] /f
```

In this case too I can see it "stopped".

This service handles some HTTP communication and when I tried it, it fails.. so I can see it succeeds. However this service also handles some TCP IP communication which still seems to work.

So looking at the command it says "This service is Stoppable, Pausable, Accepts Shutdown" and I wonder if Shutdown is different than Stop

Answer (score 0):

For all windows it can be different.  Refer to [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) for an example.

OnStop  and OnShutdown events can do different things depending on how the service was implemented.